# Java null.equals(object o)

Tags: java, object, null

I know it's not possible to call the equals method on a null object like that:

```
//NOT WORKING
            String s1 = null;
            String s2 = null;
            if(s1.equals(s2))
            {
                System.out.println("NOT WORKING :'(");
            }
```

But in my case I want to compare two objects from two database and these two objects can have attributes null...

So what is the method to compare two attributes, knowing that we are not sure that the value is null or filled.

This method is good or not ?

```
//WORKING
            String s1 = "test";
            String s2 = "test";
            if(s1 == s2 || s1.equals(s2))
            {
                System.out.println("WORKING :)");
            }

            //WORKING
            String s1 = null;
            String s2 = null;
            if(s1 == s2 || s1.equals(s2))
            {
                System.out.println("WORKING :)");
            }
```

I'm not sure because in this case it's not working ... :

```
//NOT WORKING
            String s1 = null;
            String s2 = null;
            if(s1.equals(s2)|| s1 == s2  )
            {
                System.out.println("NOT WORKING :'''(");
            }
```

Comment: First off, NEVER compare strings with the "==" opeartor, always compare them using the `equals(String anotherString)` method. The "==" operator is not "made" to compare String types.

Comment: In my case I do this example with String, but I don't compare String in reality :)

Comment: Do not assume that your question is stupid.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I generally use a static utility function that I wrote called `equalsWithNulls` to solve this issue:

```
class MyUtils {
  public static final boolean equalsWithNulls(Object a, Object b) {
    if (a==b) return true;
    if ((a==null)||(b==null)) return false;
    return a.equals(b);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
if (MyUtils.equalsWithNulls(s1,s2)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Advantages of this approach:

- Wraps up the complexity of the full equality test in a single function call. I think this is much better than embedding a bunch of complex boolean tests in your code each time you do this. It's much less likely to lead to errors as a result.
- Makes your code more descriptive and hence easier to read.
- By explicitly mentioning the nulls in the method name, you convey to the reader that they should remember that one or both of the arguments might be null.
- Does the (a==b) test first (an optimisation which avoids the need to call a.equals(b) in the fairly common case that a and b are non-null but refer to exactly the same object)

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the explication.

Comment: really nice approach

Comment: Note that since Java  7 this method is built-in: `Objects.equals(obj1, obj2)`

Answer (score 25):

You will need to check atleast one is not null before doing equals method -

```
if(s1 == s2 || (s1!=null && s1.equals(s2)))  {
   System.out.println("WORKING :)");
}
```

here `s1==s2` will work incase of `null==null` . But if even one is not null, then you need to check atleast s1 before doing equals.

Update:
As edited by @'bernard paulus', if you are using Java 7, you can use [java.util.Objects.equals(Object, Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 23):

Another option to use:

```
Objects.equals(identification, criteria.getIdentification())
```

> [java.util.Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)
>
> This class consists of static utility methods for operating on
>   objects. These utilities include null-safe or null-tolerant methods
>   for computing the hash code of an object, returning a string for an
>   object, and comparing two objects.
>
> Since:
>   1.7
>
> [public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))
>
> Returns true if the arguments are equal to each other and false
>   otherwise. Consequently, if both arguments are null, true is returned
>   and if exactly one argument is null, false is returned. Otherwise,
>   equality is determined by using the equals method of the first
>   argument.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the ObjectUtils class from org.apache.commons.lang

```
public static boolean equals(java.lang.Object object1,
                         java.lang.Object object2)
```

From the api docs...

Compares two objects for equality, where either one or both objects may be null.

ObjectUtils.equals(null, null)                  = true

ObjectUtils.equals(null, "")                    = false

ObjectUtils.equals("", null)                    = false

ObjectUtils.equals("", "")                      = true

ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, null)          = false

ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, "true")        = false

ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE)  = true

ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE) = false

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting a NullPointerException when doing `s1.equals(s2)` with `s1` being null is *not* because of s2 being null, but because you are trying to invoke the equals method on s1, which is null.

Try to amend it like this:

```
if(s1 != null && s1.equals(s2){ /*...*/ }
```

Also note that if s1 is not null and s2 is, you'll get a `false` back from equals, but no NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

```
        String s1 = null;
        String s2 = null;

        if(s1 != null && s2 != null && s1.equals(s2)) {
            System.out.println("equals");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not equals");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are comparing two objects.

So it should be like this

```
if(s1==null & s2 == null)  // both null but equal
   return true;
else if(s1 != null && s2 != null && s1.equals(s2)) // both not null and equal
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

True - for equal
False - for not equal

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if something is 'null' you can compare using:

```
if(s1==null)
```

If it is null it will tell you true. Problem, if you have a String that is null, you can't use the methods equals(). For this reason your third part doesn't work, because if it is equals you can't use a null pointer.

You should check first if the object is null and then if it isn't null use the methods equals.

On the other hand be careful because maybe you want to compare the empty String, in this case you have to use equal(""). If you want to compare the empty string, is better that you put first the empty string on this way:

```
"".equals(YourStringNotNull);
```

Sorry for my English I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking a dot operator (call method or object properties) on null object will **always** throw RuntimeException (***Exception*** are the static members as they don't belong to the object but to the class).

The chunk of code works only because || is a shortcut operator:

```
 String s1 = null;
 String s2 = null;
 if(s1 == s2 || s1.equals(s2))
```

it **does not evaluate the right side** if the left side is true.

Same for the &&: it does not evaluate the right side if the left side is false.

Comment: If `s1` is null and `s2` isn't, you're still going to execute `s1.equals(s2)` and get a NullPointerException.